# Dynamically request Android permission

Tags: android, dynamic, permissions

Is it possible to dynamically request Android permission?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android M introduces new run-time permission model which allows you to do this.

Answer (score 4):

Yes,If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target SDK is 23 or higher.

code snippet:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(),Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE}, 1);
            }
            int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE);
            if (result == 0)
                 // function which uses the permission
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From targetapi>22 android need to have runtime permissions for performing some operations,Following is the code for requesting permission at run time in android

```
//checking wether the permission is already granted
  if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,    
                 Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS) ==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

  // permission is already granted
  

    }else{

       //persmission is not granted yet
       //Asking for permission
       ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]   {
           Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},REQUEST_CODE);

    }
```

The above code is for requesting read contact permissions. Similarly you can request other permissions also based on your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

### This solution address devices targeting API < 23, for 23 and above see [Aun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32865264/1129332) answer.

While many will answer this question with NO, and will tell you that it is a security risk, I found a way!

Take a look at [ASTRO File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro), one of the famouse file manager application for android. It can brows your SD-CARD, show your images, videos and the most interesting thing, it can install APKs!

So theoretically if I created an app that did not request for internet access during the install time, I could attach an APK inside my Raw library and install it in run time, and place all my permissions there. After that it's easy only a meter of applications communications. You can do this with broadcast or shared application id(read about it first it might be risky)

From user experience it will looks like you are asking a permission in run time.

Comment: @Babibu: "From user experience it will looks like you are asking a permission in run time" -- no, it will look like you are installing an app that happens to request particular permissions. You cannot silently install an app, so the user will have to tap through a couple of screens (including the list of permissions) to complete the installation process. The user will also see your app in the list of installed applications, etc. What you are describing is a plugin model, which is a fine technique, but should not be confused with "dynamically request Android permission", which is not possible.